# how to define a type for an existing npm plugin module?

Tags: typescript, npm, nodemailer

I try to convert a codebase which uses [nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com) and the [nodemailer-html-to-text](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemailer-html-to-text) plugin to typescript.

Nodemailer has [@types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/nodemailer) definitions, but `nodemailer-html-to-text` has not.

**How can I create my own type definitions for this module?**

---

I tried to create a `@types/nodemailer-html-to-text.d.ts` file in my project:

```
declare module 'nodemailer-html-to-text' {
}
```

From here, I would like this file to export a `htmlToText` function definition of type [Mail.PluginFunction](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/86ab4d56fa27a429827c24c8ff05971e9ca766de/types/nodemailer/lib/mailer/index.d.ts#L156), but I don't know how to do it…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it here [module-plugin.d.ts](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-plugin-d-ts.html):

```
declare module 'nodemailer-html-to-text' {
  import * as Mail from 'nodemailer/lib/mailer'
  export function htmlToText(): Mail.PluginFunction
}
```